# Index usage in derived table of UNION ALL and lots of databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have a database design which has a separate DB for separate customer data. The database has a Data table which contains right now in one month ~4 million rows.

For queries I create custom views which map a customer id to a specific database. The Views look like this:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = MERGE VIEW DataView AS

SELECT
  100 AS CustomerID,
  c1db.Data.*
FROM
  Customer100_DB c1db

UNION ALL

SELECT
  101 AS CustomerID,
  c2db.Data.*
FROM
  Customer101_DB c2db;
```

Now my queries generally look like:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DataView WHERE CustomerID = ... AND ....;
```

My issue is that the corresponding index in the Data table is not used when querying the view as soon as it contains at least 2 databases.
I.e. when removing the [...]UNION ALL SELECT...[...] from the view it uses the index fine or when querying the Data table directly.
Is there a design issue here or is there any way for me to give the optimizer a better chance to push down the index (using MariaDB 10.3)?

Comment: I just duplicated the DB on a local PostgreSQL installation and the query time changed from 37s to 0.47s. Impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes and views just don't work well in MySQL/MariaDB, although they are getting better.

I would advise you to combine all the data into a single table.  You can partition the data by customer, if most queries will be on a single customer.

With the data in a single table, you can use an index.

Comment: That's what I read too and thought about as well although the application right now is basically: every customer has an isolated application inserting in his own SQL database and then I use a multi source replication to just have a separate DB per customer. I wanted to avoid mixing data from 2 customers into one table if possible.

Comment: @DanielMierswa . . . You should probably create an analysis database for *your* purposes that periodically combines the data from the different customer databases.  You don't need to give any customers access to this version of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use index hints:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html
So, your syntax could be:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = MERGE VIEW DataView AS
SELECT
100 AS CustomerID,
c1db.Data.*
FROM
Customer100_DB c1db USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)
UNION ALL
SELECT
101 AS CustomerID,
 c2db.Data.*
FROM
Customer101_DB c2db USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index);
```

Comment: I just gave that one a shot, using USE INDEX changed nothing although FORCE INDEX changed the runtime to a good half (36s -> 18s). I think the problem still is that MySQL/MariaDB builds the whole UNION although the filter on the outer query wouldn't need the whole UNION.